# $\int \phi d\mu = 0, \forall \phi\in D(\Omega)\implies \mu(A) = 0$ for all $A\subset\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on the real line. I want to prove $\int \phi d\mu = 0,  \forall \phi\in D(\Omega)$ ($C^{\infty}$-functions with compact support) then $\mu(A) = 0$ for all $A\subset\Omega$. Actually I am not even sure that it is true. But how do I start?

**Edit**

I am not sure that this works for all measures. For the special case where the measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite on compact sets, we can say that the characteristic function on the ball $\chi_{B(0,n)}$ is integrable so we can approximate it by $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions (using mollifiers) then  $\mu(B(0,n)) = \int \chi_{B(0,n)}d\mu = \int lim\phi_n d\mu = lim \int \phi_nd\mu = 0$. So every bounded set will be of measure $0$ by subadditivity.

Comment: For any set bounded measurable $A$, convince yourself that it's possible to approximate $1_A(x)$ with compactly supported functions.

Comment: Maybe given the set $A$ we can construct a $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with compact support $K\supset A$ such that $m(K)-m(A)<\epsilon$. Then $\mu(A)=\int 1_A(x)d\mu=\underbrace{\int(1_A(x)-\phi)d\mu}_{\le \mu(K)\epsilon} + \underbrace{\int \phi d\mu}_{0}$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have $\mu(A)=0$

Comment: But I am not sure how to find $\phi$ as in the first sentence